# Boundedness in $W^{2,p}(\Omega)$ for all $1\leq p<\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, sobolev-spaces

Assume $\Omega$ is nice and $\{u_n\}$ is a bounded sequence in $W^{2,p}(\Omega)$ for all $p\in [1,\infty)$, could we find a subsequence that converges strongly $u_{n_k}\to u$ in $\mathrm{C^2}(\Omega)$?

Comment: If $p > 1$ is large enough, then there is an $\alpha(p) \in (0,1)$ so that $W^{1,p}$ embeds continuously into $C^{0,\alpha(p)}$.  $W^{2,p}$ is just those $W^{1,p}$ functions for which the first order partial derivatives are also $W^{1,p}$.  Hence Arzela-Ascoli will give you what you want.  (See the Sobolev embedding theorem for the claim concerning Holder continuity.)

Comment: So $u_{x_i}\in W^{1,p}$ and thus in $C^{0,\alpha}$, so $u_n\to u$ in  $C^1$, but $u_{x_ix_j}$ is only in $L^p$ at most, how to show $u_{x_ix_j}\to u_{x_ix_j}$ in $C$?

Comment: Ah, you're right, I miscounted.  Now the issue is that you can find functions $u$ that are in $\cap_{p = 1}^{\infty} W^{2,p}(\Omega)$, but not in $C^{2}(\Omega)$.  (Even being in $W^{2,\infty}(\Omega)$ is not enough to put you in $C^{2}(\Omega)$, just as being in $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ just misses $C^{1}(\Omega)$.)

Comment: You do not even get *strong* convergence in $W^{2, p}(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not even if you have boundedness in $C^2(\overline \Omega)$. Since this space is infinite dimensional, closed balls are not compact.